# uploading foto's with camera does not work in webView android

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I am trying to create a webView for my web application in which i also can upload pictures using camera, i get the option to choose between camera or file manager and the file manager works perfect. With the camera option it opens the camera but when i then click on capture and send it does not return anything and does not load the img into the input field.

After doing some research i figured out that response.getData().getDataString() does not return anything when using the camera to capture a picture but does return something when using the file explorer to send a picture

Here is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.webview.android;

import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResult;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.PermissionRequest;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.karan.churi.PermissionManager.PermissionManager;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView webView;
PermissionManager permissionManager;

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private String mCM;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUM;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUMA;
    
    private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> imgFinished  = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult response) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                        Uri[] results = null;
                        //Check if response is positive
                        if (response.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                            if (null == mUMA) {
                                return;
                            }
                            if (response.getData() == null) {
                                //Capture Photo if no image available
                                if (mCM != null) {
                                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCM)};
                                }
                            } else {
                                Log.e(TAG, "TEST5");
                                String dataString = response.getData().getDataString();
                                Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(response.getData().getDataString()));
                                if (dataString != null) {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "TEST6");
                                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        mUMA.onReceiveValue(results);
                        mUMA = null;
                    } else {
                        if (null == mUM) return;
                        Uri result = response == null || response.getResultCode() != RESULT_OK ? null : response.getData().getData();
                        mUM.onReceiveValue(result);
                        mUM = null;
                    }
                }
            }
    );
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://hbwfc-acc.9knots.nl/app");
        WebSettings MyWebviewSettings = webView.getSettings();
        MyWebviewSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        MyWebviewSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        MyWebviewSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        MyWebviewSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        MyWebviewSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        MyWebviewSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        MyWebviewSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        MyWebviewSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        MyWebviewSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        MyWebviewSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        MyWebviewSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    request.grant(request.getResources());
                }
            }
    
            //For Android 3.0+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg){
                mUM = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("*/*");
                imgFinished.launch(Intent.createChooser(i,"File Chooser"));
            }
            // For Android 3.0+, above method not supported in some android 3+ versions, in such case we use this
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType){
                mUM = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("*/*");
                imgFinished.launch(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"));
            }
            //For Android 4.1+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture){
                mUM = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("*/*");
                imgFinished.launch(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"));
            }
            //For Android 5.0+
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                    WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                    WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams){
                if(mUMA != null){
                    mUMA.onReceiveValue(null);
                }
                mUMA = filePathCallback;
                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if(takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null){
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try{
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCM);
                    }catch(IOException ex){
                        Log.e(TAG, "Image file creation failed", ex);
                    }
                    if(photoFile != null){
                        mCM = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    }else{
                        takePictureIntent = null;
                    }
                }
                Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                contentSelectionIntent.setType("*/*");
                Intent[] intentArray;
                if(takePictureIntent != null){
                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                }else{
                    intentArray = new Intent[0];
                }
    
                Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
                imgFinished.launch(chooserIntent);
                return true;
            }
        });
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
        permissionManager = new PermissionManager() {};
        permissionManager.checkAndRequestPermissions(this);
    }
    public class Callback extends WebViewClient{
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed loading app!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    // Create an image file
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException{
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "img_"+timeStamp+"_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File tempFile = File.createTempFile(imageFileName,".jpg",storageDir);
        return tempFile;
    }
```

here is my manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.webview.android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO"/>
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I expect it loads a img file into the input field

Comment: `i figured out that response.getData().getDataString() does not return anything when using the camera to capture a picture` Indeed. You should only check if the picture is taken. Then use `File photoFile` to get your image file. To do so it should be declared directly in your activity..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by replacing

```
Uri.fromfile(photoFile)
```

with

```
FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, photoFile)
```

this creates a url tot he taken image in the same way as when you open a image from the file explorer